# Mysql error getting the previous dated record

Tags: php, mysql

First a select a row from 'table'

```
$query_set1 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ordinal = 5555 ";
$set1 = mysql_query($query_set1, $table));
$row_set1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($set1);
```

Then I want to select the previous dated record

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table WHERE date < %s) ", $row_set1['date']);
```

I get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '08:43:30)' at line 1

And this is the interpreted $query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table WHERE date < 2014-08-07 08:43:30)
```

Comment: You need single quotes around date constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that you need single quotes around the date constant.

However, why bother moving the date from the database to the application?  Just use one query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date < (SELECT date FROM table WHERE ordinal = 5555)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I separated the queries because I need both records (ordinal=5555 and the previous dated one)

Comment: I used this LIMIT 1 solution to get the previous and the next dated records and it worked. Still don't know why the MAX-MIN way doesn't work